# Replacing three 'a' in with a single '*' in a string

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, replace, while-loop

So my program should get input from an user and store it in an array. After that if the input string includes three 'a's in a row it should be replaced with a single '*'. However I can't seem to get it right. It only replaces the first a with a *. I tried to replace the following 2 a with a blank but the output looks funny. 
For this exercise I have to use `putchar()` and `getchar(`).

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char c;
char buffer[256];
int counter= 0;
int i;

int main()
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {

        buffer[counter] =c;
        counter++;

        if (counter >255) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<256; i++) {

        if(buffer[i]== 'a'&&buffer[i+1]=='a'&&buffer[i+2]=='a')
        {

            buffer[i]= '*';
            buffer[i+1]=' ';
            buffer[i+2]=' ';

        }
        putchar(buffer[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[i + 1]` and `buffer[i + 2]` have the potential for out of bounds access: that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: `for (..,i<256` --> `for (...,i<256-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my program should get input from an user and store it in an array.
>   After that if the input string includes three 'a's in a row it should
>   be replaced with a single '*'. However I can't seem to get it right.

You almost got it! Just move index by `2` to and `continue`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char c;
char buffer[256];
int counter= 0;
int i;

int main(void)
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {

        buffer[counter] =c;
        counter++;

        if (counter >= 255) {
            break;
        }
    }
    buffer[counter] ='\0';

    for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if(buffer[i]== 'a'&&buffer[i+1]=='a'&&buffer[i+2]=='a')
        {
            buffer[i]= '*';
            putchar(buffer[i]);
            i = i + 2;
            continue;
        }
        putchar(buffer[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
123aaa456aaa78                                                                                                                               
123*456*78
```

Comment: i have a question regarding the continue statement. what exactly does it do in the if statement?

Comment: @momonosuke `continue` forces program to go to the `for(i=0; i<256; i++) {` right away. It skips the second `putchar(buffer[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the number of characters, you will need to create a different buffer to copy the output to.

If you really just want to output to the console, you could just write every character until you hit your matching string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char c;
char buffer[256];
char output[256];
int counter= 0;
int i, j;

int main()
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {

        buffer[counter] = c;
        counter++;

        if (counter >255) {
            break;
        }
    }
    buffer[counter] = 0;


    for(i=0, j=0; i<256; i++, j++) {
        if(buffer[i] == 'a' && buffer[i+1] == 'a'&& buffer[i+2] == 'a')
        {
                output[j]= '*';
                i += 2;
        }
        else
            output[j] = buffer[i];

        putchar(output[j]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In string you must assign a end of character at the end and that is call null character `\0` or just a numeric `0`. Correct your code like below:-

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {

    buffer[counter] =c;
    counter++;

    if (counter >=255) {
        break;
    }
}
 buffer[counter] ='\0';// or buffer[counter] =0;
```

To avoid side effect in a string array always set all its value with `0` first:-

```
  char buffer[256];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- there is no reason to make all these variables global. Declare them locally in the body of the `main` function.
- use `int` for the type of `c` as the return value of `getchar()` does not fit in a `char`.
- you do not check for `EOF`.
- your test for buffer overflow is off by one.
- you do not null terminate the string in `buffer`. You probably make `buffer` global so it is initialized to all bits 0, but a better solution is to set the null terminator explicitly after the reading loop.
- to replace a sequence of 3 characters with a single one, you need to copy the rest of the string.

You can use a simple method referred as *the 2 finger approach*: you use 2 different index variables into the same array, one for reading, one for writing.

Here is how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];
    int c;
    size_t i, j, counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < sizeof(buffer) - 1; counter++) {
        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;
        buffer[counter] = c;
    }
    buffer[counter] = '\0';

    for (i = j = 0; i < counter; i++, j++) {
        if (buffer[i] == 'a' && buffer[i + 1] == 'a' && buffer[i + 2] == 'a') {
            buffer[j] = '*';
            i += 2;
        } else {
            buffer[j] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
    buffer[j] = '\0';   /* set the null terminator, the string may be shorter */
    printf("modified string: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```